# Adding to JQuery script runtime

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a project where it would be very useful to be able to parse some text from e.g. a database to jQuery.

An example would be this line:

```
$(container).show("drop", { direction: "bottom", distance: 300 }, 800);
```

This works great when I hardcode it into my file - but what I would like to be able to do is store this:

```
.show("drop", { direction: "bottom", distance: 300 }, 800);
```

in e.g. a database and then retrieve it at page rendering and use it in my jQuery code.

I'm currently rendering the stored jQuery out into a hiddenfield, but whenever I try to combine the values:

```
$(container) + $("#hfJquery");
```

All I get is a text-string - which makes sense. So the question is - is there any way to append code to a jquery code block in a way so that the plain text from the hiddenfield will be treated as jQuery code and not text?

Comment: likely numerous simpler approaches than trying to run code from text in a hidden field... what is reason for that approach?

Comment: It sounds as if your *really* wanting to convert your `.show()` text string markup into a **jQuery plugin**, which you can. `$(container).myShow();`

Comment: what language you use for the application?

Comment: @EdgarZavala what difference does server language make? OP trying to manage client side coding

Comment: I'm trying to write a custom data type for the Umbraco CMS which allows me to use jQuery animation on my different Document Types. But the database behind Umbraco is generic by design so it'll only store data in some simple form like a string - so if I wan't my custom control to store the selected animation, duration and parameters - then I'll have to store them as a string in the DB. 

Which brings me back to the original problem when I wan't to use these values in my scripting files :)

Comment: it does, if he is trying to render an stored piece of code from the database, something like $(container).<%= varwhichcontainsthedata %>, if i understand correctly he is storing the information on a database as an string and tries to render it back executing it as code on the view (as a jquery code). If I did not understand correctly then you are right.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see the point in doing something. But take a look at `eval()`:

http://jsfiddle.net/yP9ZL/1/

```
eval("$('#containerID')" + $("#hfJquery").val());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store the data as JSON. This would only occupy one field in DB.

You would then output to javascript object variable or store it in `data-` attributes of markup:

```
var data={
  "selector": "#Div",
  "animMethod": "show",
  "effect": "drop",
  "options": { "direction": "bottom", "distance": 300 },
  "duration": 800  

}

function runAnimation(data){
   $( data.selector)[ data.animMethod] ( data.effect, data.options, data.duration);

}
runAnimation(data);
```

The JSON could also be added directly to an element in a `data-` attribute

```
<div class="run_animation" data-animData="{animMethod: 'show'.....,  duration: 800 }">
```

Then retrieve from element:

```
$('.run_animation').each(function(){
  /* retrieve data object from markup*/
  var data=$(this).data('animData')
  $(this)[ data.animMethod] ( data.effect, data.options, data.duration);    
})
```